# NSCalendar - DateFromComponents return me wrong date! Don't understand why

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I work with the TapKu library for calendar.

And I want to display in UIAlertView the date selected.

In comments, I put the value of "info". 
The function which return the NSDate is this one :

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCa lendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:tz];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[comp setDay:info.day]; // day = 31
[comp setMonth:info.month]; // month = 11
[comp setYear:info.year]; // 2013
[comp setHour:info.hour]; // 10
[comp setMinute:info.minute]; // 0
[comp setSecond:info.second]; // 0
[comp setTimeZone:tz]; // GMT (GMT) offset 0
NSLog(@"COMP BEFORE CHANGING = %@", comp); // It displays the up infos
return [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
// The return value is : 2013-12-01 10:00:00 +0000
```

Why the return value is wrong? It's completely not the date I wanted. It added one day to 
31 november 2013

Help please, this problem make me crazy lol

Thanks

Comment: November only has 30 days. November 31st *is* December 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely correct !!!

Because November have only 30 Days.

Comment: Oups... Yes, I even didn't check the calendar. 
It's completely correct.

Because in tapku Calendar, there is a var called selectedDay.
And sometimes it's completely wrong.
It makes some calculation etc...

I will try to fix my problem. 
Thanks, Now maybe it will be easier.
(Shame on me that I didn't check the calendar, sorry for this useless post)